# inline styling in html

Tags: html, css

How can I include inline styling that functions like the `<strong>` or `<u>` tags?

```html
<strong> strong text </strong><div style="color:rgb(160, 160, 160)"> inline styled text </div>
```

I would like this to show "**strong text** inline styled text" all on one line, where 'inline styled text' is colored with a light grey.

Comment: use span not div

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [<span />](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)

```html
<strong> strong text </strong><span style="color:rgb(160, 160, 160)"> inline styled text </span>
```